# Vagrant broken with Ruby 'Segmentation Fault' Error

Tags: ruby, vagrant

All of a sudden Vagrant is broken on my machine.
I don't see what might have caused this. It came up with an older version of Virtualbox and Vagrant 1.9.8. I updated both to the current version in hope to get it fixed.

I run

- Windows 10 Pro 1709
- Virtualbox 5.2.0-118431
- Vagrant 2.0.1

I was using a current Ruby installation in parallel but removed it for testing.
For any Vagrant command I get this error:

https://gist.github.com/cfoellmann/b8c50dc386d241d44ed0fca60e7680d1

I have read about issues with the `ffi` gem but I see no way to fix the bundled components of the vagrant install.
Any pointer into debugging this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Vagrant uses its own embedded/bundled Ruby, so your system installations will not impact it.

Comment: I know (now). But do you have any pointers to find out why on my machine on a fresh Vagrant install this issue comes up? There must be some conflict with my machine otherwise more Win10 users would complain of a broken Vagrant

Comment: I would back off to older Vagrant. Hashi does not really have a build/release system or follow semantic versioning code addition procedures for their software, especially regarding comprehensive tests, so if you find a recent version that actually works for you, stick with it unless there is a compelling feature in a newer version. For example, I run 1.9.6 since they broke `validate` some in 1.9.7, and also they broke the DNS in boxes at some point around then too, but I have a quickfix for it.

Comment: I just moved back to Vagrant 1.9.4 (read about someone having luck with that one; might test 1.9.6 though) and VB 5.1.x and it works. Thanks for your findings. Too bad that vagrant is that "unstable".